# Does $|f(\sqrt{xy})| \le |\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}|$ imply $f$ is a logarithm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations, symmetry, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, functional-inequalities

Let  $f:\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function, and suppose that

$$ |f(\sqrt{xy})| \le |\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}|, \tag{1}$$

holds for every $x,y \in \mathbb R^+$.

Suppose also that $f(1)=0$, and that 
$$ x> y > 1 \Rightarrow |f(x)| \ge |f(y)| , \,\,\,0<x< y < 1 \Rightarrow |f(x)| \ge |f(y)| \tag{2}$$

(so $f$ penalizes when you get further away from $1$).

> Does $f(x)=c\ln(x)$ for some constant $c$? If not, are there "many" such functions?

Note that without condition $(2)$, **every positive increasing convex function** would do (would satisfy $(1)$):

$$ \sqrt{xy} \le\frac{x+y}{2} \Rightarrow f(\sqrt{xy}) \le f(\frac{x+y}{2}) \le \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2},$$

where the first inequality is due to monotonicity and the second one is due to convexity.

Finally, note that the "linear penalization" $f(x)=|x-1|$ does not satisfy condition $(1)$. (Take $x \to 0, y \to 1$).

Comment: You might as well get rid of the basis $a$ and just ask whether $f(x)=c\ln{x}$.

Comment: Thank you, you are right of course.

Comment: With $g(x) = f(e^x)$ your relation (1) becomes $|g((x+y)/2)| \le |g(x) + g(y)|/2$.

Comment: Just intuitively, it seems that you could construct a counterexample by taking $\log x$ and making it 'more convex' in places.

Comment: Combining the previous comments, it seems that if $g\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is any nonnegative convex function with $g(0)=0$, then $f=g\circ\log$ satisfies your two properties. For example, $g(x)=x^2$ leads to $f(x) = (\log x)^2$.

Comment: How about $f(x) = x - 1$. Note that we take absolute values in $(2)$.

Comment: @ShivTavker: $f(x) = x-1$ does not satisfy (1), try $(x, y) = (1/4, 1)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many such functions.

Choose an arbitrary convex function $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which is decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$ and increasing on $[0, \infty)$ with $g(0) = 0$. Then $f(x) = g(\log x)$ satisfies condition (1):
$$
 f(\sqrt{xy}) = g\left( \frac{\log x + \log 
y}{2}\right) \le \frac{g(\log x) + g(\log y)}{2} = \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2}
$$
and also condition (2).